# Ubuntu 13.10 as a bluetooth audio sink for A2DP supported TV

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have a Panasonic TH-L50DT60 which supports A2DP audio streaming over Bluetooth. I have a netbook running Ubuntu. I edited my `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` by uncommenting these:

```
Enable=Source
SCORouting=PCM
AutoConnect=true
```

I tested whether my laptop receives audio by connecting a Nexus phone. I played a song on the phone and there was audio output from laptop speakers.

After this, I did a Bluetooth scan on the TV to see if it detects my laptop as an audio sink. But it failed to show any devises. But my laptop Bluetooth stack sees the TV as a A2DP audio source. As TV is the audio source and it should detect my laptop as an audio sink and it is not happening. I have many Bluetooth devises and TV detects none. So, how can I get my TV to detect my laptop as an A2DP audio sink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your COD (class of device) in main.conf.

During the Bluetooth discovery process, certain devices may "see" your device but will not ennumerate it in their list of available devices because it is not advertising the major or minor class that the remote device is looking for. In this case you would probably want to change your laptop cod to something that traditionally has an audio sink role, such as a speaker or headset so your TV will ennummerate it in its list. See [the Bluetooth SIG assigned numbers](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/baseband) for reference.

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't work too.

Comment: @nixnotwin, try changing your cod. I have had issues connecting to devices that were resolved by changing my cod.

Comment: I got it working by changing the cod. If you repost your comment as an answer to my question, I will accept it.

Comment: Good to hear -- I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The last 3 lines of `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` are commented, just uncomment those lines deleting the hash in front of them, leave like that:

```
[A2DP]
SBCSources=1
MPEG12Sources=0
```

This worked for me, now just connect to your headset and use `a2dp`. It should shows Bluetooth headset on audio configurations.