# bluetooth does not appear in pulseaudio as a possible source/sink

Tags: 14.04, sound, android, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I am trying to setup my `ubuntustudio` 14.04 , 64bit as a bluetooth audio sink (service `a2snk` in a2DP), so that I can redirect music from the android phone to the pc and from there to my speakers.

I am following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2573/can-i-use-my-computer-as-an-a2dp-receiver/109533#109533) guide which even though older can still work without too many modifications, up to the point where I have to load

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluethooth-discover
```

Now, installing the module works as expected. But loading the module fails, so even though phone -> pc audio connection has been established, no bluetooth device pops up in pulse-audio and as such I hear no sound from the speakers.

This module appears in `pulseaudio` :

```
pactl list short modules | grep blue
9       module-bluetooth-policy 
22      module-bluetooth-discover
```

Checking `syslog`, it states the following related info

```
Dec 14 12:32:19 starmaze NetworkManager[1243]: <info> (50:32:75:B3:DA:31): new Bluetooth device (driver: 'bluez' ifindex: 0)
```

where `50:32:75:B3:DA:31` is indeed the bluetooth MAC address of my android phone.

and a little later

```
Dec 14 12:38:47 starmaze pulseaudio[2663]: [pulseaudio] module-bluetooth-device.c: /org/bluez/942/hci0/dev_50_32_75_B3_DA_31 is not a valid BlueZ audio device.
Dec 14 12:38:47 starmaze pulseaudio[2663]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-bluetooth-device" (argument: "path=/org/bluez/942/hci0/dev_50_32_75_B3_DA_31 address=50:32:75:B3:DA:31 profile=a2dp_source source_properties=device.icon_name=blueman card_properties=device.icon_name=blueman"): initialization failed.
```

From these other threads:
[AU1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438085/ubuntu-13-10-as-a-bluetooth-audio-sink-for-a2dp-supported-tv) , [AU2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498304/bluetooth-receiver-not-listed-in-list-sinks-even-though-paired) , [AU3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473708/ubuntu-14-04-lts-bluetooth-does-not-function-can-not-establish-an-audio-sink-co) , [AU4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370254/how-can-i-get-the-a2dp-output-option-and-the-input-working-again) , [AU5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236188/why-do-i-only-hear-sound-from-the-speakers-with-a2dp-headset-connected)

running `pulseaudio -k` does not seem to solve the issues and a contradictory statement to `Disable=Socket` in `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf  actually makes the service "a2dsnk" as broadcast from the pc to the phone to disappear.

What could be wrong?
I guess the problem is pinpointed in a failure to load the bluetooth-discover module in pulseaudio or something related. But with all the info (sometimes contradictory) out there, I can not be certain. Can you help?

EDIT:

`lsusb` returns

```
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

`lsusb -t` returns

```
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
```

`lspci` and `lspci -nnk` are over in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wacFtyq2). Not sure how this will help so I included all the output.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @SantaClaus it was always a problem of my bluetooth dongle. `0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle` is apparently notorious for not working correctly. so close, but no cigar...

Answer (score 2):

On my system this problem was caused by gdm starting a pulseaudio client and grabbing the bluetooth audio card before the user's client could. I fixed it by disabling pulseaudio for the gdm user:
in

```
/var/lib/gdm/.config/pulse/client.conf
```

added:

```
autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true
```

Comment: This worked for me on 16.04 Beta 1 running on Dell XPS 13 9350

Comment: Suppose I want to fix this without rebooting. What command should I run if gdm has *already* grabbed the audio card? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This command might fix your issue

```
 sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Comment: nope the module is already loaded..

Comment: It seems that everything should be fine. I mean I can play audio from phone to the pc, but no bluetooth sound source appears in pulseaudio playback devices

Comment: Can you include the results from `lsusb -nnk` and `lsusb` as it might be an issue with needed firmware on the PC's bluetooth device

Comment: Hi there, info is included, but `lsusb -nnk` returns "invalid options' for both "n" and "k". did you mean something else perhaps?

Comment: yes I did `lspci -nnk` and `lsusb`

Comment: ok here it is...

Comment: I still need result from lsusb

Comment: it's in here after "EDIT"

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/reviews/B001EBE1LI?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0  I would find another bluetooth device, the one review shows it has the same 0a12 0001 ID that yours has and says A2DP doesn't even work in Windows, a search for 'bug 0a12:0001 A2DP brings a long list of results also

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort. the dongle seems buggy indeed. however, none of the searches brought up my problem. Some get sloppy sound https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/460743 , other state that this dongle works fine compared to others (!) https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56791 !! One seems to have the same problem, but they blame it on the dongle getting powered up before the kernel boots https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1289042.html .

Comment: I, for one, feel that I should get the bluetooth audio to appear in pulseaudio sources list and then and only then can I judge the sound. because if I can't see bluetooth audio source in pulseaudio, I can only assume the problem is either with the bluetooth driver (which has worked for others though), or with pulseaudio bluetooth modules.... don't you think?

Comment: Have you tried the idea about booting with the bt dongle unplugged and plugging it in later

Comment: yes, always been doing that.